# Multiple post comment system

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

I have a stackoverflow style comment system where there are a variable number of posts ("answers") on a page that people can comment on.  I am trying to use jquery to grab a unique selector of a users comment, submit it into a mysql database and display it, all without refreshing. The trouble is that i don't know how to select an individual comment, because the comment's need to have a unique selector and right now they are all under the same class (.commentBox).

JQUERY:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
$('document').ready(function(){

$('.submitCommentBox').click(function(){

            var comment = $('  //idk ').valu();
            var questionid = $(' //idk  ').val();
            var answerid=$('  //idk  ').val();

    $.post('../comment.php',
    {

    comment: comment,
    questionid: questionid,
    answerid: answerid,


    },
    function(response){

        $('#commentContainer').load('../writecomment.php');

    });

}):

});

</script>
```

HTML (this is in a while loop and echos multiple times depending on number of posts):

```
                 <div class='answerContainer'>
                    <p name='singleAnswer' value='$answerid[$f]'>$answer[$f]</p>
                    <p>$answeruser[$f]</p>
                    <p> $time[$f] seconds</p>
                    <p> $answerrating[$f]</p>
                    <form id='form$c'>
                    <div id='commentContainer'></div>
                    <textarea class='commentBox' placeholder='...comment' wrap='soft' name='comment' value='$c'></textarea>
                    <input type='button' value='submit' class='submitCommentBox'>
                    </form>
                    </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of the wire up on the submit you can do it on the form and just change the submit button to type="submit".

```
$('.addCommentForm').submit(function(){
    $.post({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '../comment.php',
        data: $(this).serialize(),   // $(this) referring to the source form that triggered the submit.
        success: function(data, textStatus, jqXHR) {
            // Do whatever like add the display only equivalent of the comment
            // that was just submitted if successful.
        }
    });
    return false; // Prevent the form from actually submitting the old fashion way.
});
```

I'd refer to the jquery api for this for more details.  http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/